Verify a Token on Solana
I have a client who have deployed a token and wants me to verify it so that shows up as a verified token when people are researching it –
Here is the token address, can anyone help
https://solscan.io/account/DsCDAZ7do54sGgQan4GxMD5Qy4dABB3RExo2b9ncDq5y

Most platforms use the Jupiter strict list to check whether a token is verified or not.
The criteria you need to meet for this includes

Be at least 21 days old
Have daily volume of more than 10K
Have a market cap of more than 100K
Have unique metadata (Symbol and Name does not duplicate another project on the community list)
Have more than 500 unique holders

ref: https://station.jup.ag/guides/general/get-your-token-on-jupiter
